# How to send to the current channel room and the opposite channel room to show messages on both ends?

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I was thinking of creating a model that handles saving and creating the groups like so:

```py
# Something like this perhaps...
class OneOnOneRoom(models.Model):
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique=True)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Group {self.room_name} initiated by {self.sender} for {self.receiver}'
```

Then in the connect method for my consumer I need to create two rooms somehow, so I could broadcast all the messages from user A or user B to be sent to both of the rooms so that both users can see each other messages.

So if user A is `http://localhost:8000:chat/B` and user B is on `http://localhost:8000:chat/A`; user A should send data to his own channel and the channel for B; user B should send data to his own channel and the channel for B.

Is this a good solution to do this? I can not think of any better solution right now– either way I found no way to actually send to multiple channels at once in channels. Any tips?

What I have been trying and thinking:

```py
#asgi.py
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": django_asgi_app,

    "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter([
                re_path(r"ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$", ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
            ])
        )
    ),
})

#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:room_name>/', room),
]

#views.py
def room(request, room_name):
    return render(request, 'chat/room.html', {'room_name': room_name})

#chat/room.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Chat Room</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chat-log">
      <!-- Messages will be displayed here -->
    </div>

    <form id="chat-form">
      <input id="chat-message-input" type="text" size="100" autocomplete="off">
      <input id="chat-message-submit" type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>

    {{ room_name|json_script:"room-name" }}
    <script>
    const roomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('room-name').textContent);

    const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
      'ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/chat/' + roomName + '/'
    );

    console.log(chatSocket)

    document.querySelector('#chat-form').onsubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault(); 
      const messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input');
      const message = messageInputDom.value;
      chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
        'message': message
      }));
      messageInputDom.value = '';
    };

    chatSocket.onmessage = (e) => {
      const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
      const chatLog = document.getElementById('chat-log');
      const messageDiv = document.createElement('div');
      messageDiv.textContent = `${data.user}: ${data.message} | Posted : ${data.date}`;
      chatLog.appendChild(messageDiv);
    };

    chatSocket.onclose = (e) => {
      console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
    };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

#consumers.py
class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        current_user = self.scope['user']
        other_user = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        # Should send to both of these,
        # self.room_group_name = f'group_{current_user}_{other_user}'
        # self.room_group_name = f'group_{other_user}_{current_user}'
        # But the room_group_name should change based on who is logged in. 
        # If user A then f'group_{current_user}_{other_user}' example and then the opposite user B

        if not await self.check_room_exists(room_name=self.room_group_name):
            await self.create_one_on_one_room(sender=current_user, receiver=other_user, room_name=self.room_group_name)

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json["message"]
        # Data from client side comes here but it only sends to one of the defined room_group_name[s]
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name, {"type": "chat_message", "message" : message})

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        user = self.scope["user"]
        message = event["message"]
        date = str(datetime.now().strftime("%c"))

        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({"user": user.username,"date": date, "message": message}))

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_user(self, username):
        return User.objects.get(username=username)

    @database_sync_to_async
    def check_room_exists(self, room_name):
        return OneOnOneRoom.objects.filter(room_name=room_name).exists()

    @database_sync_to_async
    def create_one_on_one_room(self, current_user, other_user, room_name):
        return OneOnOneRoom.objects.create(sender=current_user, receiver=other_user, room_name=room_name)

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_one_on_one_room(self, room_name):
        return OneOnOneRoom.objects.get(room_name=room_name)
```

EDIT:
Unless there is better ways to create a one-to-one chat then tell me.